# Firebase: Secure and atomic transfer of "credits" between user accounts

Tags: firebase

A transaction of x “credits” from user account A to user account B. Security constraint: The transaction can only take place if there exists a corresponding `application` from user A to user B with status `accepted` and amount x. Once the transaction is complete the application status needs to be set to `resolved`.

Is it possible with Firebase to implement this transfer of credits atomically, so I don’t end up with inconsistent data e.g. lost or generated credits, application status not ‘resolved’...

I see how I can enforce the aforementioned security constraint with Firebase’s rules, since I can reference and compare to data in arbitray paths within them.

But Firebase’s transactions seem to only operate on a single path. So the only solution I see is implementing credits and applications on a single path and a user’s number of credits is calculated by their history of ‘applications’. Is this solution feasable?

Comment: It certainly is possible. Read this article for an in-depth explanation by one of the Firebase engineers: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-02-04-firesafe-complex-security-logic-for-firebase.html

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, I've come across this article before. It looked overly complicated, so I was wondering if there was a simpler solution. Will give it a thorough read now!